# Customer Can Buy a Product Once and Can be Purchased alone

Tags: product, cart, rules

In Magento, I have some products, which can be purchased only once by a customer, and this products can be purchased alone not combined with any products.

Eg. 
1) If the Product `X` purchased by a customer `C`, then when the customer `C` again try to purchase the product `X` , it should not allow him to purchase.

2) The Product `X`, can be purchased alone only, when the customer add the Product `X` to cart, then it needs to check whether already any products are in cart,

- if no, then this product can add to cart
- if yes, then this product should not add to the cart, need to show
  some notification and need to redirect to product page.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain why you need this, what type of product so we understand what it is about.

Comment: This Product is about some thing like membership, so if a user already membership should not be again to pay for it.

Comment: Do you allow guest checkouts? Do you force people to log in before they can place items into the cart?

Comment: guest checkout not allowed to this product.

Comment: The customer no need to `log in` to add this product to cart

Answer (score 1):

For situation 1 it's easy. Add a new product for each X to the catalog. Set stock to 1, and don't allow backorders. We do this as well for one type of product which is handmade and has different specs for each item.

I don't know why you would want to have situation 2. Is this a shop where you can only order 1 thing at a time? What will customers prevent from making another order?

Comment: if i setting stock as 1, then if a customer buy this product then this product will be in out of stock so other customer can't able to purchase. i wants to sell this product for unique customer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you will need to create an extension with an observer that watches for the quote_totals, something like the following: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/tag/event-observer/

You will be able to check against your conditions in the observer, dealing with it as you have to.

Another option would be to do it at the template and/or block level.

Checking against the conditions there may be easier, but this would not be as future-proof.